# Why I can't define FindViewById() on Fragment with Volley Library

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, android-volley, findviewbyid

I am trying to define `FindViewById()` on Fragment with Volley Library. Also, I put `FindViewById()` on method `OnResponse()`, but I am getting an error. Do you have any solution? Here is my code.

```
package com.smktelkommlg.prakerinlistview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "Some Base URL";
    private final String EndPoint = "Somr EndPoint";
    List<Result> resultsLists;
    ListView listView;

    public SecondFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
        resultsLists = new ArrayList<>();
        listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ProgressBar progressBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rolling);

        loadResultsList();
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String idToDetail = String.valueOf(resultsLists.get(position).getId());

                Intent detailIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),DetailActivity.class);
                detailIntent.putExtra("idMoveIntent", idToDetail);
                startActivity(detailIntent);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private void loadResultsList () {
        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, BASE_URL+EndPoint+"?limit=1000&offset=0", new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

               ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.rolling);

                Log.d("Json Response", response);
                try {
                    
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray heroArray = obj.getJSONArray("results");
                    for (int i = 0; i < heroArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject heroObject = heroArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Result superHero = new Result(heroObject.getString("name"), heroObject.getInt("id"), heroObject.getJSONObject("device_role").getString("name"), heroObject.getJSONObject("status").getString("value"), heroObject.getJSONObject("device_type").getJSONObject("manufacturer").getString("slug"));
                        resultsLists.add(superHero);

                    }
                    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(resultsLists, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap header = new HashMap();
                header.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                header.put("Authorization", "Token eaaa9e72d1a4f4c75aef7a7492e07785d853b6b4");
                return header;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(stringRequest);

    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated (@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Results");
        getContext();
    }
}
```

I can't define this `ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.rolling);`
Do I have to put `ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.rolling);` in `OnCreateView` and use `rootView`? What should I do?

I meant to call progressBar before receive through the API.
(I'm sorry  for my grammar. I hope you understand)

And here's my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/rolling"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Global Variable

**In your SecondFragment:**

```
ProgressBar progressBar;
```

**in OnCreateView:**

```
progressBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rolling);
```

Remove `ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.rolling);` from loadResultsList() method.